# Created a VHD using dsk2vhd, no boot

Tags: windows, display, vhd

I've got a complete installation of Windows 7 Ultimate and used the tool dsk2vhd to create a vhd of the instance of Windows 7 within that same instance - it seems to create it no problems (no error messages are given). When I then add this newly created vhd to the boot menu using something like EasyBCD, I get both boot options available (the original Windows 7 installation and the VHD), but whenever I select either of them, nothing boots, all I get is a blank screen.

Fortunately, I had a backup of the boot menu so I could restore it, but I'm at a loss why this is happening.

Comment: The reason your are having problems is because the two installations are conflicting with one another.  Have you tried installing it to an entirely seperate disk, imaging that, then mounting that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried EasyBCD myself.  I used the directions on Technet here.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-boot-from-a-vhd.aspx

I'd follow these direction first.  EasyBCD questions are best posted to their support forums.